# Chrome data compression proxy error with jquery ajax PATCH method

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, proxy, compression, http-patch

I am having web page make ajax HTTP PATCH call to the same domain restful service. It failed ONLY for mobile phone for chrome browser, like the below

```
$.ajax({
url : "same-domain/path",
data : "{}",
type : 'PATCH',
headers: {
    "Cache-Control":"no-transform",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
},
processData: false
}); // failed ONLY if any payload presented
```

> Status Code:502 Bad Gateway
>
> This page cannot be loaded via the Chrome Data Compression Proxy. Try
>   reloading the page.

This is quite annoying since all we tested desktop browsers and mobile NOT-chrome can do PATCH successfully. Actually, mobile chrome does succeed ONLY if no any payload

```
$.ajax({
url : "same-domain/path",
data : "",
type : 'PATCH',
headers: {
    "Cache-Control":"no-transform",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
},
processData: false
}); // is OK ONLY if no payload at all
```

K. thanks for some related discussion here so i know the cause. I wish this can fix this and respect cache-control header. And meanwhile, what is your way to walkaround?

Comment: What if you use POST instead of PATCH?

Answer (score 1):

I am the tech lead for the Chrome compression proxy. Can you share more details such as the URL used? PATCH should be supported by the proxy so I am surprised you are seeing this issue.

Comment: Is there a way to disable proxy for certain requests? Like for a captcha image? As captcha content is saved in SESSION, but the session is valid only between proxy->server, and not on the enduser->server route.